# Eclipse java debugger: esclude some lines from Step Over

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, custom-build-step

I'm debugging a java source and I want that a group of instructions must be executed at same press of Step Over.

Something like this:

```
debugcursor -> int a=10;
               int b=a+a;
               a=b*b;
               a++;
```

And, after pression of "Step Over":

```
               int a=10;
               int b=a+a;
               a=b*b;
debugcursor -> a++;
```

Is it possible to do it without any breakpoints and use of Step Run?

Comment: place break points and at first and next statements and press F8

Comment: What is your problem with the "standard" behaviour? Do you face multi threading issues? If so rethink your design...

Comment: I say not use of breakpoint, here is a simple example, but my situation include DSL, XBase...breakpoints don't solve my situation. Is it possible to do it WITHOUT them?

Comment: @TommasoDS All of us had answer your question as you defined the situation, explain the problem with real code to get the solution of your problem

Answer (score 1):

You **DONT** have any other option other than using `BreakPoints` along with `Resume (F8)`.